# Uniformly convergent series

Tags: uniform-convergence

Why series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\vert{x}\vert}}{n^3}$ is uniformly convergent in $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$?

My answer: ${{e^{-\vert{x}\vert}}  \le1 }$ for  $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$ implies $\frac{e^{-\vert{x}\vert}}{n^3} \le$ $\frac{1}{n^3}$, which is convergent and hence by Weierstrass $M$-test given series is uniformly convergent.

Please correct if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct. Since $e^{-|x|}\leq 1$ for all real number $x$, it follows that the series 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\vert{x}\vert}}{n^3}$$
is uniformly convergent in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @dipali mali Any more doubts? BTW would you like to take a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour